AsyncClient logging input/output body
Can AsyncClient be extended and parametrized to log the body of input and output of every external call for reuse in multiple methods that use the same AsyncClient?
import json
import logging

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from httpx import AsyncClient

# Set up basic configuration for logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

app = FastAPI()
client = AsyncClient()


@app.get("/example_post")
async def example_post():
    url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"  # Free fake and reliable API for testing and prototyping.
    payload = {
        "title": 'fooxxx',
        "body": 'bar',
        "userId": 1,
    }

    # Perform the HTTP POST request; would like to log input payload and output data response
    response = await client.post(url, content=json.dumps(payload))

    # Parse response as JSON
    data = response.json()

    # Searching for universal solution that can log request and response of every api call instead of logging manually
    logging.info(f"Received response: {data}")

    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)


@Chris marked this question as duplicate and it is not the same problem. I need to log AsyncClient input and output not request on my endpoint ( in this case example_post) but on URL

Request body
When it comes to logging the request body, you should consider event hooks.
Here's the doc : https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/event-hooks/.
And here's how you could implement it :
from httpx import AsyncClient
from httpx import Response, Request

async def log_request(request: Request):
    print(f"Request event hook: {request.method} {request.url} {request.content} - Waiting for response")

client = AsyncClient(event_hooks={'request': [log_request]})

Response body
As for the response body, things are a little more complicated, as the body is a stream that can only be consumed once.
To get around this, you could consider writing your own transport layer. You can refer to this answer: https://github.com/encode/httpx/discussions/3073#discussioncomment-8263619
